# How to get text from input area

Tags: python, selenium

i am trying to get the coordinates after i specified the adress by using this site

https://www.gps-coordinates.net/ lets assume that we passed in into adress input Italy Vatican and after we passed the adress the Longitude and and the latitude values are appearing however there is no text when ve right click and inspect the element. How can i get the Latitude from the input area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the latitude value after a small wait for page load.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.get("https://www.gps-coordinates.net/")
time.sleep(5)
elem=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#latitude")))
print(elem.get_attribute('value'))
```

Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```